# How to fix final render causing issue by having pixelation using cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This is a fbx file imported to blender originated from C4D and having an issue with Cycles render. Just like what you see on the below, preview looks fine but the final render has this weird pattern shape. All the other parts are okay but only the faceplate is having a problem. All I did so far is added new materials and changed color. Is there any possible way I can fix this? I am new to blender so it would be graceful if I get some help with this. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: How does your shader look like?

Comment: I just added new screen grab! above shader is all I did. Just changed color. Everything seems fine except for that front faceplate

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

This looks like an issue known as Z-fighting. What that means is you have some geometry that is very close together, so close that the camera doesn't know which one is on top, thus you get a mix of both.

From your images it looks like there is a blue shell that overlays the white body of the controller.

To fix this, a possible option is to remove the part of the white body that is under the blue shell. This will get rid of the geometry that is too close, and also make it faster to render since there will be less geometry.

Another possible (and much easier) option to try is changing the *Clipping* settings in *Camera* tab of the Properties Panel on the right. Try increasing the start value (to something like 1) or decreasing the end values (to something like 30-50). Typically adjusting the start value will be more effective.